# Can't find tkinter module in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tkinter, importerror

I'm working in Eclipse with pydev and have a very simple tkinter program.  When I run it from Eclipse, I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named tkinter.

However, I can run the exact same program from the command line and it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure same Python version is used in Eclipse and command line?

Comment: That did the trick!  It took a bit of noodling around with the Run Configuration dialog, but I got it to work.  Thanks.